# Inserted Picture is referenced instead of inserted when using VBA Picture.insert(path)

Tags: vba, excel

I use the following code to insert a logo into an excel chart:

```
ActiveChart.Pictures.Insert("path\logo.jpg").Select
```

I see the logo and everything is fine from my point of view. But if i send this file via e-mail to a collegue which doesn't have access to the path he cannot see the picture. From this evidence i conclude that the code references the picture instead of inserting it.

**How does one insert a picture permanently, such that the logo will be visible even if the path is not accessible anymore?**

Comment: Is the path you are using an absolute path, meaning is it something like "C:/User/Pictures/..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To embed the image in the file you have to add a shape and then put the image in the shape using `AddPicture`

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture "C:\documents\somepicture.jpg", False, True, 1, 1, 100, 100
```

This example comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908538/using-vba-to-insert-and-keep-images-in-file-excel-2013)

MSDN also has some information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addpicture.ASPX)

Comment: I got a follow up question you might be able to answer too.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47829743/inserting-shape-causes-inconsistent-in-vba-excel