# Inserting shape causes inconsistent in VBA excel?

Tags: vba, excel

This is a follow up question to [`LINK`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828388/inserted-picture-is-referenced-instead-of-inserted-when-using-vba-picture-insert?noredirect=1#comment82620394_47828388)

The code used to insert a image into an excel chart is the following:

```
 Set logo = Application.ActiveChart.Shapes.AddPicture("path\logo.jpg", False, True, 1010, 650, 110, 60)
```

Two problems arise through this:

## 1 shape size is not what was used as input

The shape width and height should be what was used as function input. In this case 110 width and 60 height. This however is not the case, the top and left parameters do also not match with the input.

## 2 The formatting of the chart get "thrown-off"

By this I mean font sizes change shapes get moved around and the best part is: if i stop at the code line above the behaviour is different.

**How does use the function such that these "funny behaviours" do not occure ?**

Comment: Can you give an example of `font sizes change shapes` ?

Comment: @ashleedawg The font sizes of the x and y axis change from 14 to 8 and the ChartArea gets moved. I have tried this without the "set logo=" and then this does not occure but now I am still curiouse why this happens.